# TC command via webpage as a sudo

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, perl, traffic-filtering

The main goal- run a `tc` command via webpage, starting with:

```
tc qdisc del root dev eth0
```

(deletes all the filters)

Following [Simple linux commands from a webpage](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-linux-commands-from-a-web-page/step6/Adding-a-feature/)
I am trying to add a tc command, but there is a need for sudo in order to do that (otherwise- operation not permitted).
Therefore running:

> /sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0

has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the user that runs the web server to the sudoers file first.

Something like this - replace `www-data` with the user that runs the web server

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0
```

That will let the www-data user run `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0` without a password.

If you need to add more commands, then you can tack them onto the end with a comma like so

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0,/sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth1
```

Once the sudoers file is setup, then when you run the webpage that runs the command, as long as the webpage is running `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0` it should work.

Comment: I've added this line to the sudoers file, however it did not solve the issue.
i have tried to add myself myuser which is not an admin user instead of www-data and run the command and I've received "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

the line that I've added is 
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0

Comment: Can you run the same command as root ?

Comment: if you are talking about sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del root dev eth0 then I can. After running this command, I use tc qdisc show to see that all filters are off.