# tc packetloss cgi script via webpage throws AH01215: Illegal “loss percent”

Tags: linux, script, cgi

Using the following [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-linux-commands-from-a-web-page/step4/The-main-program/)
to run CGI commands, and after fixing [a small issue](https://superuser.com/questions/783376/tc-command-via-webpage-as-a-sudo)
 executing `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem loss 1%` returns an error `AH01215: Illegal "loss percent"` (at apache error.log)

I am able to run `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 1ms` though (which confims that running `tc` commands do work)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `%` character after the parameter itself fixed the issue:

```
`sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev em2 root netem loss "$LOSS"%`
```

The parameter $LOSS is taken as a string without the `%` character:

```
`echo "<input type=radio name=cmd value=network_loss> Add Packetloss: <input type=text name=loss value=0.5>%<br>"`
```

(See the linked [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-linux-commands-from-a-web-page/step4/The-main-program/) for more information about the script)